# PHP Respect Relational - Update from a specific column

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was studying a little about the [Respect Relational](https://github.com/Respect/Relational) class library and ended up with a question despite having read all the documentation. Can I make an update on a record where the primary key column is not named "id"? For example:

I applied my test on a table where the primary key has a 'tb_' prefix in its name:

```
    tb_id
    tb_nome
    tb_sobrenome
```

When I want to get the record I use:

```
    $user = $mapper->user(array(' tb_id' => 1))->fetch();
```

To make the update I use:

```
    $user->tb_nome = 'Alexandre';
    $user->tb_sobrenome = 'Gaigalas ';
    $mapper->user->persist($user);
    $mapper->flush();
```

But it does the following error 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE [42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column' id 'in' where clause '', because the search for the Class ID field that does not exist in this table.
It would be possible to specify which field I want it to do the update? For example:

```
    $mapper->user(array(' tb_id' => 1))->persist($user);
```

Comment: Probably better to post on [Stack Overflow em Português](http://pt.stackoverflow.com) instead of relying on Google Translate.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not written in English. It probably should be posted in the Portuguese site

Comment: I voted to close, but I am retracting it, because the question is now entirely in English, and the translation seems okay. OP: if you do ask this question on the other site, please let us know here - thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This mapper like many database classes depends on the use of a naming convention.  As stated in the readme, the convention is to have the primary key column in a table be named id, and to have foreign key fields named table_id.  It does support "styles" which are classes that make adjustments to the internals so that it can support a separate convention.  However, in your case, you don't have a convention at all, due to the use of the tb_ prefix before every column.  It's not clear to me what a foreign key column would be named in your database.

With that said, the way to handle your mapping issue would be to create your own style class and apply that using the mapper as in the documentation example:

```
$mapper->setStyle(new MyStyle);
```

If you look at the style classes, your best bet is probably to have your MyStyle class inherit from the standard style class that implements the stylable interface.  You can look at their base style classes for a better idea of how you can implement the required classes in their abstract and example classes in [the Data class here](https://github.com/Respect/Data/tree/master/library/Respect/Data/Styles).

At minimum you would need to have a new identifier method.  You could try this as a start, but it's just an educated guess on my part:

```
public function identifier($name)
{
    return strtolower($name);
}
```

Comment: My PHP level is not as advanced ... I'll try looking for another solution